# I can't use any commands on gcloud sql

Tags: mysql, macos, google-cloud-platform

```
MacBook-Air-2:~ Owner$ gcloud sql instances describe ahaha-mysql

ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.describe) There was no instance found at projects/ahaha-20180621/instances/ahaha-mysql or you are not authorized to access it.
```

Comment: Is there an instance at `projects/ahaha-20180621/instances/ahaha-mysql` and are you authorized to access it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable permission for the compute instance to access the cloud sql

1. Stop the instance
2. Edit the instance and change the Cloud API access scopes
3. Enable Cloud SQL
4. Restart the instance
5. run `gcloud auth login` and authenticate as yourself by following the link (you might need to fix it in a text editor) and entering the verification code.
6. run `gcloud sql instances describe ahaha-mysql` this should now work